# R, ggplot, Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems

Tags: r, ggplot2, melt

I want to visualize data from an acceleration sensor. I have a data frame with four columns: time (PosiXlt), AccX, AccY, AccZ (all as numeric) and around 33 million rows. Here is the head of my file:

```
    "time"              "AccX.in.G" "AccY.in.G" "AccZ.in.G"
2015-06-24 04:00:00.092 -0.789  0.516   -0.374
2015-06-24 04:00:00.102 -0.782  0.52    -0.374
2015-06-24 04:00:00.112 -0.786  0.52    -0.371
2015-06-24 04:00:00.121 -0.786  0.516   -0.374
2015-06-24 04:00:00.131 -0.782  0.52    -0.371
2015-06-24 04:00:00.141 -0.782  0.52    -0.371
```

I want to have a plot with the time as x-axis and the other three values as lines. I tried plotting with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
Molten <- melt(MSR46, id.vars = "time")
ggplot(Molten, aes(x=time, y= value, group = variable)) + geom_line()
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the dataProblems:time
```

I checked the length of all variables and they are all the same.

I therefore don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
I'm sure its simple but I just don't get it.

Can someone please help me?
Thanks

here the

```
 dput(head(MSR46,10))
```

of my file:

```
"","time","AccX.in.G","AccY.in.G","AccZ.in.G"
"2",2015-06-24 04:00:00.092,-0.789,0.516,-0.374
"3",2015-06-24 04:00:00.102,-0.782,0.52,-0.374
"4",2015-06-24 04:00:00.112,-0.786,0.52,-0.371
"5",2015-06-24 04:00:00.121,-0.786,0.516,-0.374
"6",2015-06-24 04:00:00.131,-0.782,0.52,-0.371
"7",2015-06-24 04:00:00.141,-0.782,0.52,-0.371
"8",2015-06-24 04:00:00.151,-0.782,0.52,-0.378
"9",2015-06-24 04:00:00.161,-0.786,0.52,-0.374
"10",2015-06-24 04:00:00.171,-0.782,0.52,-0.374
"11",2015-06-24 04:00:00.181,-0.782,0.52,-0.371
```

Comment: Including the output of a `dput()` is always better to give some ample data, e.g.: `dput(head(MSR46, 10))`

Comment: Did you try `color = variable` instead of `group = variable`?

Comment: And if what @Jaap suggests doesn't work, try both, i.e., `color=variable, group=variable`.

Comment: I tried bot,     color=variable' and "color=varialbe, group=variable".
Sill doesn't work

Comment: Does the problem persist in an empty environment/new session? Because with your sample data/code I could not replicate your error.

Comment: It's an empty environment and I also tried a new session

Comment: I also couldn't replicate the problem with the data provided. Most likely you have NA's or NULL's somewhere in your data. Otherwise try to provide the dput() of minimal amount of data that replicates the error

Comment: NOTE: (to answerers): this is _most likely_ Coursera homework.

Comment: the file should not contain NA'S or NULL's since I deleted them. I added the dput() of the file in my question and even with these 10 rows I get the same error.
Can u replicate it now?

Comment: That's not the output of a `dput()`. You only have to copy the output. It looks like this: `structure(...etc...)`

Comment: Look at Molten. I think something is going wrong with reshape2 and the class of PosiXlt.

Comment: I don't know why, but reshape doesn't work well with PosiXlt. Does it work if you convert your time variable to POSIXct before melting?

Comment: @Heroka was right: converting the time to PosiXlt solved the problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pedde hooray! For future questions, please provide the appropriate data that's asked for. (`dput()`). It would lead to a faster solution....

Comment: I would have liked to, but the dput() output was just too large!?